# HTML, CSS - print table to a fixed grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am trying to print a HTML table on an A4 paper with tags 10 x 4. That means I need to print one cell per tag, the cell has to hold an exact position in the page. I already resigned on using Firefox, which seems absolutely dumb here. I am using Chromium instead and I do not mind if it is the only browser it is working in.

Now let's specify the problem: I have HTML tables, each of 10 rows and 4 columns. My idea is that a table = a page. The problem is that some weird things are happening at the bottom of certain pages.

My CSS looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
        td
        {
            width: 24%;
            text-indent: 3mm;
            font-size: 12px;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: inline-block;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        tr
        {
            height: 10.4%;
        }

        table
        {
            page-break-before: always;
            height: 297mm;
            width: 210mm;
        }

        p
        {
            margin-top: 0mm;
            margin-bottom: 0mm;
        }

        body
        {
            margin: 0mm;
        }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page
        {
            size: A4;
            margin: 0mm;
        }
    </style>
```

This seems to be working well enough - the only issue is that I get an empty page in between each two pages. If someone has an idea how to strip those, I will be happy with that, although it is not a proper solution.

When I remove the `page-break-before: always;` property, the blank pages disappear. But the issue is that starting with page 8 onwards, the height of the last row is ignored and is sticked to the previous one. If someone has an idea how to force the printing engine to maintain the height of the row, the problem will be solved. In the browser, everything looks ok.

I have searched Google for a very long time and I am getting bored with that, as I cannot find an appropriate site.

Sample data for testing can be found [here](https://github.com/frantiseksimorda/lsum/blob/master/sample.html)

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Comment: When shrinking the table (page) height to 295mm, the blank pages disappear, in exchange for 2mm extra border...another almost perfect solution, though not proper.